# Int32 not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
//Comp454 program 2
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream> // file I/O support
#include <cstdlib> // support for exit()
const int SIZE = 60;

int main()
{
 using namespace std;
 string states;
 int numStates = 0, i = 0, stateVar = 0;
 string line;
 char filename[SIZE];
 ifstream inFSM, inString;

 //Open FSM definition
 cout << "Enter name of FSM definition: ";
 cin.getline(filename, SIZE);
 inFSM.open(filename); //Associate inFile with a file
 if (!inFSM.is_open()) // failed to open file
 {
 cout << "Could not open the file " << filename << endl;
 cout << "Program terminating.\n";
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 //Process FSM definition line by line until EOF
 getline(inFSM, states);
 numStates = Int32.TryParse(states);

 //Check for num of states
 if(numStates > 10)
 {
  cout << "There can be no more than 10 states in the FSM definition, exiting now." << endl;
  return 0;
 }

 while (!inFSM.eof()) // while input good and not at EOF
 {
  getline(inFSM, line);
  cout << line << endl;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to convert a string to an integer using Int32.TryParse(), but when I compile I get the error that Int32 was not declared in this scope.  Not sure why this is coming up, am I missing a namespace declaration??  Any help is appreciated, thank you

UPDATE:
Thanks for all the responses, as in the comment I posted, I'm not trying to use C++/CLI, how to I convert a string, declared from the string class, to an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [atoi()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) instead. States is a std::string so you will need to say:

```
numStates = atoi( states.c_str() );
```

Comment: I'd rather advise `strtol`, as `atoi` has no error-reporting mechanism (you don't know if you've parsed a number equal to zero correctly, or if you've failed to parse a string which is not a number - in both cases you get `0` from `atoi`).

Answer (score 2):

[Int32::TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) is not a native C++ API. Its [`C++ \CLI`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) method.
You will have to use .NET Framework and include the namespace `System` to get it working.

If you just want to convert the string to integer, you can use: 
[atoi()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) or refer FAQ : [How do I convert a std::string to a number?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.2)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are compiling a straight-C++ application using the .NET `Int32` class to parse a value.

You'll either need to reference the `System` namespace and CLR support if you are indeed compiling a .NET application, or use a function like [`atoi()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) to parse your string value.